# Why does Label text passes to the method but textinput text doesn't?

Tags: python, kivy

If you run my code, you will see that Label's text passes to the other method of the same class but Textinput text does not.

*note= i want to send the input text from the user not the text of the TextInput (because the TextInput text can be sent)

I didnt left 'self' out (its a nested method) if i write it before the lbl txt and btn then nothing would work. I am new to python therefore to kivy too, so forgive me if my question is stupid.

So again how can i send the input text from TextInput to the other(def randmeth()) method?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyGrid(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        kk = 'some random key'
        SLB = Label(
            color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
            text=str(kk))

        TXT = TextInput(
            text='',
            size_hint=(.75, 1))

        BTN = Button(
            text='OK',
            background_color=(.2, .2, .4, 1),
            font_size='13sp',
            size_hint=(.75, 1))

        BTN.bind(on_press=lambda *args, btn=SLB.text, txt=TXT.text: self.randmeth(btn, txt))
        self.BLT = BoxLayout()
        self.BLT.add_widget(SLB)
        self.BLT.add_widget(TXT)
        self.BLT.add_widget(BTN)
        self.add_widget(self.BLT)

    def randmeth(self, val1, val2):
        print('apfc', val1, val2, '...')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I think that by passing the text attributes in via keyword arguments you bind using the value at the moment of creating the lambda function. For the TextInput, the text is empty, which is what you see. Try something like `lambda button: self.randmeth(SLB.text, TXT.text)`.

Comment: Actually it didnt work sorry, but i forgot to mention that this is not my real code i just simplified it, so its easier to read. In my real code there is a `for` loop before i create the `LBL, BTN`  and `TXT` and when i use your suggested  code `lambda button: self.randmeth(SLB.text, TXT.text)` then it only passes the last key's value in the dictionary

Comment: Then post a question demonstrating your problem.